# How To Specify Open With Notepad2 (for example) Using PHP serverside script

Tags: php

I have spent a few days on a personal productivity tool and am currently stuck.

What I have, is a WebSite, running on an Apache Server on my wee Aspire notebook.
The website isn't anything fancy; just the usual php/html/css.  The idea, is I would like to be able to access my notebook's harddrive/file system, and open my files, without having to leave my website and use Explorer.

So far, I have successfully figured out how to use the HTML Upload File Dialoge; which opens the common dialog box.  I am able to browse, select a file, and click on open, and then back on the webpage, click Submit.  The file is being successfully brought into my server, and the few lines of code *fopen* etc., works fine for displaying text inside a div.

Also, I puzzled out the bits and pieces to copy a file which was for instance, in some folder OUTSIDE of my Folder which is used for my server.  That Folder, the one I keep all my website files, jpgs, txt, html, php files ~ all the things for my development projects, has proper permissions (as far as I know). But initially, as I was building the toy, when I tried to click on a link I placed on the webpage, for instance:

```
<a href="A File.txt">Open This Puppy </a>
```

I'd get a message in my browser about the file not being found on localhost.... and I realized it was just that I needed to have the file in my website accessible Folder.  Hence the dodge to actually copy my *Upload* selection into the accessible folder.

You're a hero for reading this far... here's the thing.  **I want, when I click on a link on my webpage, for my Windows 7 to open, whatever file that is.  Say it's "Never Give Up.odt"; then have Open Office open that file,  OR, "How About Those Cubs This Year.TXT" and I want NotePad2 to open up.**

Anywhooo in 3 days of trying to find out if it is even possible, I haven't hit on search terminology that turns up anything of interest or help.

Sure would appreciate a hint, or help.  Thank you.

Comment: Do you want the link to the file to force a download and open with the appropriate application? Are you attempting to force which application opens the file as well?

Comment: I don't submit this as an answer because I'm not sure if I understood you. So, this seems impossible (not 100% sure, but nearly) to do with PHP: PHP is serverside and you're clientside. PHP could only open on it's own server. You'll have set some settings in your browser, I guess. If I misunderstood you, please tell.

Comment: For clarity... if I am using Windows Explorer and click to open a file with a .txt; I have things set so Notepad2 app starts, and opens with the file I selected, displayed, ready to read and write etc.  The goal is to get exactly the same action, from clicking on a link on my webpage.  Again, this is a page running on my Apache Server, on the same machine ~ everything built in my notebook, it just seems weird that I haven't been able to find info on what particular techniques or languages or processes to study to get it done.  Thanks for your interest.

Comment: Hey, @axiomer; thanks to you as well.  1ne Acer Notebook, check.  Got a server set up, running smooth for over a year.  Check.  There's the folder with all the website files, and outside, other folders.  So, I am working in my website, and decide I need to get some info from a text document.  As is, I can open the HTML Upload, and I bring the document, say, "Suspicious Goats.TXT" into my Server.  Good.  Can open and read it, but not write etc.  Also, I copy the file from its original location, into the folder the server uses.  So, from on my website I click a link and it works, sorta... :) ...

Comment: But what happens, is the browser, Chrome, opens the document "Suspicious Goats.TXT" in the browser, full screen, scrollable etc., but it ain't the same as having the file open in Notepad2.  I can't edit the document in the browser and save it etc.

Comment: @Josh ah... yes I want to have the file open in Notepad2.  So far, all I have managed is Getting Chrome to go to the file and display the contents in my browser.

Comment: @MountainMan Consider Quentin's answer. That is your best answer.

Comment: This is odd, I added some comments, in response to Josh and to axiomer, and they were visible for a few minutes then disappeared.  Does stackoverflow treat comments as chat or email or something?  Anyhow, back to working the puzzle.

Comment: Oh, wierd.  I can suddenly see all the comments again.  Hello Josh.  Thanks, I'll get to looking at that straightaway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. You can only say "This is a file of type X". It is up to the browser to decide what to do with files of that type.

This will be:

- Open in browser (if supported by the browser or a plugin)
- Open in application
- Save
- Prompt to open in application or save

You can generally force a save with a Content-Disposition header, but you can't force and open or determine which application will be used.

Comment: I'm missing this link http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type from your answer and maybe this one http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_association#Implementations + word on `header('Content-Type: ...')` but anyway +1

Comment: Hello @Quentin, appreciate your time!  Looking at those articles, then looking at the current lines in the webpage Header, gave me an idea; here's what is there now:< meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; 06   charset=iso-8859-1" > and if I get the gist of what this is regarding, I could add some other items, seperated by one of those | thingys? say, add content="text/plain" | content="application/pdf" | content="application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text to handle Open Office text files, etc?  I'll go try something like that now, but don't see how that gets the App Open thing, yet

Comment: Maybe, maybe not... where de comments dey no go neh?  excuse my, guys, just trying to figure how these comments work

Comment: Hokey Dino! humbled this question got any attention from someone in with so much activity and reputation.

Comment: @MountainMan — Meta tags are not HTTP headers, they can pretend to be them sometimes, but as far as content-type is concerned, only the charset is of any interest. They also apply to the current document, not things linked from it.

Answer (score 0):

Two-phased solution.
1. On click, open the text file in a new tab by specifying target="_blank"
   Force the text file to send data to browser by specifying a new MIME type, such as text/x-text-on-notepad or something like that.
2. Build an application to "plugin" to your browser, which in turn opens notepad whenever the MIME is found.

But I suggest you don't do it :)

Comment: Hello, @Akshay.  Alright, so the <a href= etc. gets treated with the target="" and so far so good, ... and building a plugin? well... no idea what's involved in that, but I can check it out. Now curious, why would you suggest I not do the things you suggest may be helpful in solving this challenge?  I mean, sure I can leave the webpage, click down on the Windows Explorer icon and use the Windows 7 stuff and open the file I want to work with; but it would be easier, faster and Cooler to be able to do that from my webpage.  Cheers!